# LDAP query to fetch all reports

Tags: ldap, openldap

I need to extract all the people managed by a particular manager ("report"). Each person has a "manager" attribute which point to the manager. I can search on the manager attribute - but this only finds direct reports. If we have a second-level manager, it doesn't find their whole team.

I realise I can use the search query repeatedly, but this could get slow when people have a large team. Especially as I don't know if a particular user is a manager or not - until I do the search query.

Is there a single LDAP query to fetch all the reports? I'm using openldap. A similar kind of query is possible in SQL using CONNECT BY or WITH RECURSIVE.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) in openLDAP and most LDAP implementations you have no choice but to do repeated LDAP Queries.
(Note the word **Lightweight** )

Microsoft Active Directory has a really neat Extensible Matching Rule they call [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-QueryAllUsersThatReportToADepartmentManagerOrTheirSubordinates.) which can be used for such purposes, but, it only works on Microsoft Active Directory.

Comment: Hey

Ok. But is there any way by using `grep` and some repeated queries manually.

Comment: Of course there is always a way. Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask